# Even-odd sort incompatibility

Tags: sorting, java

I am new to Java and I have faced the following problem. I need to sort array of integers in ascending order so that even numbers will be in one half and odd ones in the other.

So, I have a special comparator:

```
static class EvenOddSort implements Comparator<Integer> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer x, Integer y) {
        if (x == y) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (y % 2 == 0) {
            if (x < y) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            if (x < y) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And the following sort method:

```
public Integer[] sortEvenOdd(Integer[] nums) {
    EvenOddSort customSort = new EvenOddSort();
    Arrays.sort(nums, customSort);
    return nums;
}
```

Also I have the following test:

```
@Test
public void testSortEvenOdd1() {
    Integer[] nums = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    Integer[] expected = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
    assertArrayEquals(expected, tasks5.sortEvenOdd(nums));
}
```

It fails when I run it on `openJDK6` and successful on `openJDK7`.

```
arrays first differed at element [0]; expected:<2> but was:<1> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: arrays first differed at element [0];     expected:<2> but was:<1>
```

- Could you help me to make it compatible across all `openJDK's`?
- Also, it would be great to know what I am doing wrong.

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: "It fails" is *never* enough information. Please give details. But basically your `compare` method is incorrect at the moment - trivially, consider `compare(0, 0)`. That *should* return 0, but will return 1.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've updated "fails" with fail message. `compare(0,0)` - I've updated comparator with this case.

Comment: So your next step should be to output every comparison it's making, including the result - and check whether it's what you want.

Comment: you are using Integers so should be doing x.equals(y)

Comment: @TimB or at least `x.intValue() == y.intValue()`

Comment: @TimB thank you for noticing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your whole comparator is broken, I kept seeing more problems with it.

Just do something like this:

```
if (x%2 != y%2) {
  if (x%2==0) {
     return -1;
  } else {
     return 1;
  }
} else {
  return x.compareTo(y);
}
```

First check to see if they are not both odd or both even. If they are different then sort based on odd or even.

Then if they are both odd or both even fall back to the standard Integer compare functionality.

Comment: Spoilsport. @JonSkeet was trying to teach the fellow how to debug logic problems in his program, and you just gave up the answer.

Comment: @Ordous I know. There were so many problems though that stepping through wouldn't make it easy to find them.